# how to call JSON data through URL in Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I'm practicing Web API through JSON.

In the URL I am using (https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=malaria&format=json), there are fields like `ID`, `titles` etc. I want to call title and display it. Below is my code so far:

```
app.controller("europepmc", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=malaria&format=json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.magazine = data;
    });
}]);
```

And my controller is binding with html date in the following way:

```
<div ng-controller="europepmc">
  <p>The magazine title is  is {{magazine.title}}</p>
</div>
```

After successfully developing this code I'm not able to get the title.

Comment: @LoneWolf fine it showing in console but I want to display only titles in the webpage

Answer (score 4):

The JSON you are receiving has more properties for you to go through before you can reach `title` from results. You should extent it with `.resultList.result` first. Then display this array with `ng-repeat`.

Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module("pmc", []);
app.controller("europepmc", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=malaria&format=json')
    .then(function(res) {
      $scope.magazines = res.data.resultList.result;
    });
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="pmc" ng-controller="europepmc">

    <div ng-repeat="magazine in magazines">
      {{magazine.title}}
      <hr>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Here is a demo to view the entire response:

```js
var app = angular.module("pmc", []);
app.controller("europepmc", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=malaria&format=json')
    .then(function(res) {
      $scope.magazine = res.data;
    });
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="pmc" ng-controller="europepmc">
    <pre>
      {{magazine | json}}
    </pre>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your Json object does have the title property, but a bit deeper:

object.resultList.result.0-24.title

to look at it better, paste your Json here:

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

and check the viewer tab.

Answer (score 0):

//In Angular Controller Code
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("europepmc", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

```
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=malaria&format=json',

    }).then(function (success) {
        $scope.magazineList = success.data.resultList.result;
    }, function (error) {
        alert(error);
    });
```

}]);

// HTML Page Code
Use ng-repeat to loop through mg in magazineList -- and then use mg.title

Comment: your `magazine` is undefined, since you are populating only `magazineList`